# PySpark caused mismatch column when reading from csv

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

**Edit**: The previous problem was solved by specifying the argument `multiLine` by `True`in the `spark.read.csv` function. However, I discovered another problem when using the `spark.read.csv` function.

Another problem I encountered was with another csv file in the same dataset as described in the question. It is a review dataset from insideairbnb.com.

The csv file is like this:
[image: The csv file looks like this]:

But the output of the read.csv function concatenated several lines together and generated a weird format:
[image]

Any thoughts? Thank you for your time.

---

**The following problem was solved by specifying the argument `multiLine` in `spark.read.csv` function. The root cause was there were `\r\n\n\r` strings in one of the columns, which the function treated as a line separator instead of a string**

I attempted to load a large csv file to a spark dataframe using PySpark.

```py
listings = spark.read.csv("listings.csv")

# Loading to SparkSession
listings.createOrReplaceTempView("listings")
```

When I tried to get a glance at the result using Spark SQL with the following code:

```py
listing_query = "SELECT * FROM listings LIMIT 20"

spark.sql(listing_query).show()
```

I got the following result:
[image: The output of the Spark SQL query with mismatched columns]

Which is very weird consider reading the csv with pandas outputs the correct format of the table without the mismatched column.

Any idea about what caused this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please show us the corrosponding lines of the csv file?

Comment: One of the potential reason can be delimiter position. As it seems your cab is comma delimited, you will have to enclose values with comma present in values into double quotes to avoid this. Like value for a column in csv foo,bar then it needs to be enclosed like `"foo,bar"`  to read it as one column value.